# Flutter - Set minimum width for Tab to wrap the Text child without wrap or crop the text

Tags: flutter

I've asked ChatGPT previously and it was failed to solve it.

> I have a `Row` contains a `TabBar`. The tab bar has `Tab`(s). Each tab
> has `Text` widget. I don't want to set the width for the tab bar and
> the tabs, not explicitly in any way, not even by `Expanded` nor
> `SizedBox` them. I want them to wrap their content just enough, not
> wrapping them nor padding them. I don't want to change the font size.
> I don't want to scale the text.

He gave me this.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            child: Text('Tab 1'),
          ),
          ...
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

I replied...

> It's not working! The text is cropped or wrapped!

...before he came up with his gibberish and I decided to ask here.

Comment: You started with "I have a Row contains a TabBar. The tab bar has Tab(s). Each tab has Text widget." Please show us your own code and how it looks like. Then show us what you want to achieve. Also, please share your reason for not wanting to use helper widgets like Expanded or SizedBox? I mean, if that's the only way out to achieve what you want, why not use it.